# Beautiful Soup: extract 2 different tags and append them together in text only output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been playing around with beautiful soup trying to learn it.  So far ive learned some stuff but im struggle to put my use case together.  how do i print, both movieslist and moviescore text only appended together?  appreciate the help and info.  really enjoying python and some of its applications like web scraping.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
result = requests.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/opening")
print("Checking Website")
print(result.status_code)
print("Gathering Website data and preparing it for presentation")
src = result.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')
movielist = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"media-list__title"})
moviescore = soup.find_all("span",attrs={"class":"tMeterScore"})
for movielist in soup.find_all("div",attrs={"class":"media-list__title"}):
        print (movielist.text)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key here is to "zip" the two lists you have. But before this happens you need to get the text value from each element and strip it.

Here's a slight modification of your code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


result = requests.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/opening")

print("Checking Website")
print(result.status_code)
print("Gathering Website data and preparing it for presentation")

soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')

# get each movie title and remove any whitespace characters
movies = [
    title.getText(strip=True) for title in
    soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class": "media-list__title"})
]
# get each movie score, remove any whitespace chars, and replace '- -'
# with a custom message -> No score yet. :(
movie_scores = [
    score.getText(strip=True).replace("- -", "No score yet. :(") for score
    in soup.select(".media-list__meter-container")  # introducing css selectors :)
]

for movie_data in zip(movies, movie_scores):  # zipping the two lists
    title, score = movie_data  # this outputs a tuple: (MOVIE_TITLE, MOVIE_SCORE)
    print(f"{title}: {score}")
```

Output:

```
Checking Website
200
Gathering Website data and preparing it for presentation
The Courier: 79%
The Heiress: No score yet. :(
The Stay: No score yet. :(
City of Lies: 50%
Happily: 70%
Doors: No score yet. :(
Last Call: No score yet. :(
Enforcement: 100%
Phobias: No score yet. :(
Dark State: No score yet. :(
Food Club: 83%
Wojnarowicz: 100%
```

Comment: this is perfect! i really appreciate your answer.  i am going to study this and keep learning! thanks again

Comment: @Ryang  Don't forget to upvote and "mark as answered" to give ＠baduker the karma.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a dictionary comprehension with if else to check if rating present

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

result = requests.get("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/opening")
print("Checking Website")
print(result.status_code)
print("Gathering Website data and preparing it for presentation")
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content, 'lxml')

movie_scores = {i.select_one('.media-list__title').text:i.select_one('.tMeterScore').text if i.select_one('.tMeterScore') else 'No score' for i in soup.select('.media-list__item')}
print(movie_scores)
```

Comment: would i be able to use this to print the info into the body of an email send it out using cron?

Comment: I should think so though you would need to do some research and post a new question if get stuck. Pretty sure there will be some existing answers covering this